# How to migrate data from Azure Cognitive Search To Elastic Search?

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, logstash, azure-cognitive-search

I am trying to tranfer indexes from Azure Cognitive Search to Elastic Search . I am new to both.
After some research I found that one way to do it is to use Logstash to extract data from Azure and Insert it into Elastic search.

I have found a lot of plugins between several datastores  and Logstash but none between Azure Cognitive Search and Logtash.

Can anyone point explain to me or point me toward a detailled explaination of how to ingest data into elastic search from Azure Cognitive Search?

Thank you so much.

I investigated ways to do it and found that logstash could work. However, I did not find any plugins between logstach and Azure Cognitive Search

Comment: What's the reason that led you to migrate to ES?

Answer (score 0):

I used the Azure Search Index Backup and Restore from Liam Cavanagh in the past. It worked great, but in my case was to restore an existing index/data into a different search service.

https://github.com/liamca/azure-search-backup-restore

It may be a starting point for you. I can't remember if it will output data in json or not, but the all you have to do is parse the data and push them to your Elastic Search index.